# jQuery.validate.js NOT working when using type="button" for ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I know there are lots of question similar to this but i am not getting exact solution to my situation in MVC so i am asking again.

I am new to `MVC` and i am using `jQuery AJAX` to call controller method to insert data.

AJAX function.

```
function btnLoginUser(btnClicked) {
      var $form = $(btnClicked).parents('form');

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Accueil/Login",
            data: $form.serialize(),
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            },
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

My button in form in view.

```
<input type="button" value="Se connecter" class="btn btn-success" onclick="btnLoginUser(this)" />
```

When i use this button with type="button" it make ajax call but jQuery validation stops working.

BUT when i use `type="submit"` then validation starts but ajax stops working and page is refreshing.

Button with `type="submit"`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Se connecter" class="btn btn-success" />
```

So is there any way that both should work with validation and also AJAX to insert data without refreshing page ?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Javascript call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#idUser').on('submit', function (e) {
            if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Your Ajax code
                btnInsertUser(this);

            }
        })
    });
```

And button in form is.

```
<input type="submit" value="S’inscrire" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:return AcceptTermAndcondition();" />
```

Comment: The proper way to use ajax with this plugin is to put the ajax inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.  [See documentation:  *"**The right place** to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try that :

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Your Ajax code
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use e.preventDefault(); then it unbind the jQuery.validate() event so it's not working

Comment: That's why you have to test before !e.isDefaultPrevented().
If the validation fails it triggers e.preventDefault().
If not, you do and call ajax.

Comment: Okay i will give it a try and respond in few min

Comment: Post your HTML and new JS codes; it should work, because this is what I use for the same purpose in my own applications.

Comment: Edited my question please check it and help me

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from AcceptTermAndcondition() ?

Comment: Just a question what is the jquery.validate.js you are using ?
Because there is multiple variants.

In one from DiegoLopesLima, you have to set this : "sendForm : false".

I prefer that one : [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

Comment: Jquery validation plugin

Comment: Thanks for your quick response actually your answer is helping me in preventing page refresh with working validation but actually Data is not passing from View to controller so that's a different issue. Thanks.

Comment: The proper way to use ajax with this plugin is to put the ajax inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.  [See documentation:  *"**The right place** to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)